# How to detect collision between two images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, collision, detection

I am implementing a simple game where my car (an image) has to dodge obstacles which are circles (images). Now I am having problem making a collision detection method for the car and the circle. I want the circle to disappear as soon as the car collides with it. Right now I am using an id named 'y' to show if the car collides with the bluecircle. If it does the id is used by the `<p>` tag in my HTML code section and it should display text saying "COLLISION" but even when they intersect....nothing happens... :/

```
function Intersect(ax ,ay , aw , ah , bx , by , bw , bh){
            return ax < bx + bw && bx < ax + aw && ay < by + bh && by < ay + ah;
    }
if (Intersect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h,bluecircleArray[0].x,bluecircleArray[0].y,bluecircleArray[0].width,bluecircleArray[0].height)){
                     document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = "COLLISION";
    }
```

Comment: *it doesn't work* usually needs more detail than that. The best I can assume is that, no matter where the car goes, the Y element (and I will assume you only have one element called Y in your document) never shows "COLLISION"?

Comment: ax < bx + bw && bx < ax + aw shouldnt it be like ax < bx + bw &&  ax > bx - bw

Comment: @Katana314 this is not the way i have  written code, i have just showed the function and the if condition that isn't working...let me upload the full code

Comment: @Adil.R There's no issue with the amount of detail you've shown, but "It doesn't work" in particular tends to be a slightly annoying phrase, because usually we'd like a slightly more detailed account, eg: "*I would expect when I click this button, my image would change color, but instead nothing at all happens.*" OR "*...but instead, the image disappears.*" Knowing the current symptoms is often very important to determining *what* is wrong, exactly.

Comment: @Adil.R Well, close enough. The exact text I'm thinking of would be like "*It should display text saying "COLLISION", but even when they intersect, nothing happens*". I will take a stab at this.

Comment: @Katana314 i am actually new here so if you know what the problem is....please help me out :(

Answer (score 0):

I kind of think what you wrote for `Intersect` is actually an "`IsContainedIn`" function. The natural expression of `Intersect` should be this, with added parentheses to help with order of operations:

"(Is the right-side X edge of A contained in B, OR is the left-side X edge of A contained in B), AND, (Is the bottom-side Y edge of A contained in B, OR is the top-side Y edge of A contained in B)"

And, to elaborate, "contained in", would mean:
"Is this number between B's X/Y value, and B's X/Y value plus its width"

It's quite possible that in the end, the `if` clause will get quite large.

The main problem with your current equation is that all the statements are connected with "&&". I'm not sure if it's possible for all clauses to be simultaneously true, unless possibly one of them fits inside the other in an exact way.

If you're still having trouble writing it out, there might be some tutorials on "Axis-Aligned Bounding Box Collision" that could help with it - they may also be able to give visual samples to help you get a spatial idea of it in your mind.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually new to javascript as well as canvas in HTML and thats the only reason i posted this here :p